# How to get contentType from System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat

Tags: c#, image, content-type

If I have Bitmap and it has RawFormat property.

How can I get Content Type from this ImageFormat object?

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(stream);
ImageFormat imageFormat = image.RawFormat;
//string contentType = ?
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I believe I've come up with a simple solution that works great for images. This uses extension methods and Linq, so it will work on .net framework 3.5+.  Here's the code and unit test:

```
public static string GetMimeType(this Image image)
{
    return image.RawFormat.GetMimeType();
}

public static string GetMimeType(this ImageFormat imageFormat)
{
    ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
    return codecs.First(codec => codec.FormatID == imageFormat.Guid).MimeType;
}

[TestMethod]
public void can_get_correct_mime_type()
{
    Assert.AreEqual("image/jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg.GetMimeType());
    Assert.AreEqual("image/gif", ImageFormat.Gif.GetMimeType());
    Assert.AreEqual("image/png", ImageFormat.Png.GetMimeType());
}
```

Comment: +1 for including working unit test (well, and being the correct answer)

Comment: As a small improvement it may be better to use GetImageDecoders instead of GetImageEncoders. On my system there was no encoder for EMF files. However there was a decoder.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to determine the MIME type from a file name (or extension), here is a link that uses the registry: [Get MimeType from a File Name](http://kodesharp.blogspot.com/2008/04/c-get-mimetype-from-file-name.html)

Comment: @x2 - strange, I've just clicked in my answer and it works for me. HTTP 503 (service unavailable) is supposed to be a temporary issue. You should try later on.